# Is there a way to get the hospitals near me,using the radius using bing maps?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I'm developing a wp8 app and i need to know how to get the hospitals near me using the bing maps api, or if its not possible, maybe using another api

hope someone can help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution using the google places api, and installing on the project solution the nugget package of httpClient, you can do this on the next link,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

and the final code is in here

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=YourkeyHere&location=" + lat + "," + lon + "&radius=5000&keyword=hospital&sensor=true";

string googleResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);
```

the final result is an string that has to be Deserialized from json to an object, there are many way to do this, so you can choose your own path, thanks every one for their help but this is, what i was looking for and i hope that this solution, can help someone

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL) to fetch data from the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) database.
I've tested plenty of APIs to retrieve this kind of information (google places, bing and a few others), and I found OSM to be the best way to retrieve POIs - or Points of Interest - and very nicely structured metadata.

As you can see from those links, the Overpass QL syntax allows you to search for nodes by radius (e.g., `node(around:100.0);` and by type (e.g., `node[amenity="hospital"]`).

Here's a complete list of the OSM standard tags:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features

**Bonus**: since OSM is a community project, feel free to contribute and tag any POIs you might know.

Comment: you know how to implement it on wp8?

Comment: The links I gave you teach you how to query the OSM database using the overpass API. This is done through standard HTTP calls (which can be done using the `HttpWebRequest` on WP8). You'll have to read the API documentation and learn how to build your queries.

Comment: No problem. I used this for a proof of concept application as part of my master's thesis, and I was very satisfied and surprised with how good their data was.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in bing maps.  I'm pretty sure hospitals are included as a Point of Interest by querying the [NAVTEQNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478192.aspx) data source.

Have a look at `private void FindandDisplayNearbyPOI(XmlDocument xmlDoc)` functionality in the following [MSDN Documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757509.aspx).